# Python Asyncio - wait for one specific background task to finish before starting the next

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have an app which collects data in batches. Every time it's done collecting one batch, it saves the data. In order to speed things up, I've been using asyncio so that it can *continue* collecting data *while* it's saving the previous batch, rather than halting the program while it saves.

But I've run into a problem:

Let's say my app collects Batch A and begins to save it. However, Batch B is really small,  so the program starts saving Batch B before it's finished saving Batch A. This mucks things up, it should only save one batch at a time. Here's an approximate example of what's occurring:

```py
import asyncio
import random
async def save_data():
    print("I'm saving a batch")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("I'm done saving")
    
async def collect_data():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        print("I'm collecting data")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        event_loop.create_task(save_data())

asyncio.run(collect_data())
```

Ideally, only one instance of `save_data()` should be running at any one time.

How do I ensure that the previous batch is saved before I begin saving the next one, while also having the saving done in the background?

Comment: By not using async? The question is confusing

Comment: This sounds like the job for a lock or similar sequencing mechanism. An alternative design is to use task queues that just run each kind of task in sequence - not as elegant but simple to do with all the design cruft asyncio inherited from threads.

Comment: Note that (the reason I am commenting and not answering) one generally has to mind *backpressure* here. Consider that once you get B to wait on A, *what should happen if C starts*? If you naively just delay tasks until their predecessor proceeds, your entire system can easily choke ( this is effectively a programming version of how car jams can occur without any external obstruction). One needs to communicate stalling all the way up, which at the very least means your loop also needs a mechanism to wait for tasks to proceed.

Comment: Though in this simple case - you can just `await` the previous task (which you should do anyway to handle exceptions). This may-or-may-not work in a more general situation, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, only one instance of save_data() should be running at any one time.

Well, then you have two options:

1. You block the collection until saving of the previous batch is complete. This is simple and very similar to double buffering. The downside is that performance can suffer if batches are of very different size and you might want to collect multiple small batches while saving a big one.

```py
async def collect_data():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    last_save = None
    while True:
        print("I'm collecting data")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        if last_save: # don't let saving overlap
            await last_save
        last_save = event_loop.create_task(save_data())
    if last_save:
        await last_save
```

2. Put all batches in a queue so that they are saved in order. Now you have to be careful not to overwhelm the system by collecting faster than you can save, exhausting your memory. The queue's `maxsize` argument helps prevent that.

```py
async def collect_data():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=16)
    async def save_all():
        while True:
            try:
                batch = await queue.get()
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                return
            await save_data()
            queue.task_done()
    saving = event_loop.create_task(save_all())
    while True:
        print("I'm collecting data")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        batch = ...
        await queue.put(batch)
    await queue.join()
    saving.cancel()
```

Proper exception handling is left as an exercise to the reader. The process can deadlock if `save_all` terminates with an exception. You could prevent it with something like this:

```py
    putting = event_loop.create_task(queue.put(batch))
    done, _ = await asyncio.wait({putting, saving},
                                 return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    if saving in done:
        putting.cancel()
        break
```

and similarly for `queue.join()`. There might be less verbose ways of achieving the same